# Details about part-time jobs in DS-160 form

Tags: visas, usa, f1-visas

While filling up my DS-160 form, I was not able to enter details of my part-time work in the past 5 years. After filling up details of my full-time employment, the "Add more Employment" button got disabled and I couldn't add more details.

The savings of my part-time business are the main source of my financial statement. Now if the Visa officer asks me a question regarding my past employment? Should I mention the details of my part-time business? I don't want to shock Visa officer with new information and create distrust.

Is there anyway to provide this information before hand? Can anyone provide a good solution?